# CCSprite save the effect so that next action to be performed on changed CCSprite in xcode for iphone

Tags: image, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have performed CCLens3D effect on CCsprite after action i have to save CCSprite to png. Please help me 
I have used following code

```
@implementation HelloWorldLayer

CCSprite *img;

-(void)lensEffect:(CGPoint )touchpoint
{
    const CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    NSLog(@"%f",touchpoint.x);

   // const CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    id lens = [CCLens3D actionWithPosition:CGPointMake(touchpoint.x,touchpoint.y)
                                    radius:50.f
                                      grid:ccg(20.f,20.f)
                                  duration:0.f];
    [img runAction:lens];
}
```

After [img runAction:lens]
I have to save img with action?

---

I have got the screen shot but after performing two three time lens effect the image is seems to be blur please help if u now hoe to keep resolution of image same after lens effect.

thks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a CCRenderTexture. [Set it up as described here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/) (screenshot part) and then call [img visit] to render the sprite onto the render texture.